# tabularray valign text of different point sizes

Tags: alignment, tabularray

Is there a better way of getting all the cells to vertically align to the middle than changing cell specifications based on which cell has more height?

I would like to get rid of the `\SetCell` commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={Q[h]Q[m]},
    hlines = {red5, 1pt},
    vlines = {red5, 1pt},
  }
  \Huge HUGE TEXT & Normal size text \\
  \SetCell{m}Normal size text & \SetCell{h}\Huge HUGE TEXT \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `m` specifier for `valign` tries to center *base lines*.

You can use `varwidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={
      Q[m,c,preto=\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}\centering,appto=\end{varwidth}]
      Q[m,c,preto=\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}\centering,appto=\end{varwidth}]
    },
    hlines = {blue, 1pt},
    vlines = {blue, 1pt},
  }
  {\Huge HUGE TEXT} & Normal size text \\
  Normal size text & {\Huge HUGE TEXT} \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]